# Python Multiprocessing Reading from SQS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, multiprocessing, message-queue, amazon-sqs

I have the following code that launches multiple python processes that continually poll from an SQS queue.

The processes are launched with

```
num_processes = range(1, 9)

    for p_num in num_processes:
        p = multiprocessing.Process(
            target=sqs_polling, args=(queue_name, p_num,))
        p.start()
```

and the actual polling function is

```
def sqs_polling(queue_name, process_id):

    sqs = boto3.resource('sqs', region_name='us-east-1')
    queue = sqs.get_queue_by_name(QueueName=queue_name)

    no_messages = False

    # poll sqs forever
    while 1:

        # polling delay so aws does not throttle us
        sleep(2.0)

        # sleep longer if there are no messages on the queue the last time it was polled
        if no_messages:
            sleep(900.0)

        message_batch = queue.receive_messages(MaxNumberOfMessages=10, WaitTimeSeconds=20)

        if len(message_batch) == 0:
            no_messages = True
        else:
            no_messages = False

        # process messages
        for message in message_batch:
            do_something(message)
            message.delete()
```

This seems to work for a few hours but eventually it seems as though SQS throttles the processes and no messages can be read even though they exist on the queue.  To help reduce this I have a timeout of 2 seconds between Queue reads.  Also I have created a 15min timeout if there are no messages read.  In spite of this I still get throttling.  Can anyone explain why throttling is still occurring here?  Another possibility might be that the connection to the queue gets stale but I think that is unlikely.

Comment: There is no need for the `sleep(2.0)`.  Unless you are actually getting errors indicating throttling (which you didn't mention), then that isn't what's happening -- none of my SQS code sleeps at all.  The messages in the queue, as displayed in the main page of the console... are they "available" or "in flight?"  Also, doesn't `message.delete()` return a value?  What do the CloudWatch counters for the queue show?

Comment: Since there are no errors I suppose that it is not throttling.  There are no errors at all actually.  The processes just literally stop doing anything after a few hours (even though they are in a while loop that should be constantly polling).  Completely have no idea what is going on.

Comment: Though I work with numerous AWS services, none of it's with Python... but if all else fails, add more logging.  Log the time and the process id at each iteration of the loop.  Are they even still polling?  Are they running?  Are they hanging? Terminating?

Comment: I do have logs in the while loop.  So it must be hanging somewhere in that loop.  They are not still polling.  Very frustrating

Comment: I don't see anything here that would cause logging to occur.  Add something immediately before and immediately after `message_batch = queue.receive_messages...` ... "starting poll" before, and "finished poll" after, along with timestamps and process ids. If it correctly logs "starting" and "finished" every 20 seconds, then you have reason to suspect SQS is at fault... but if it stops logging, whichever message was logged last will tell you where, in the loop, things went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit outdated, but I just released [multi_sqs_listener](https://github.com/fvinas/multi_sqs_listener) that provides a high level, multi-threaded way to listen to multiple SQS queues from Python code.

```python
import time
from multi_sqs_listener import QueueConfig, EventBus, MultiSQSListener


class MyListener(MultiSQSListener):
    def low_priority_job(self, message):
        print('Starting low priority, long job: {}'.format(message))
        time.sleep(5)
        print('Ended low priority job: {}'.format(message))
    def high_priority_job(self, message):
        print('Starting high priority, quick job: {}'.format(message))
        time.sleep(.2)
        print('Ended high priority job: {}'.format(message))
    def handle_message(self, queue, bus, priority, message):
        if bus == 'high-priority-bus':
            self.high_priority_job(message.body)
        else:
            self.low_priority_job(message.body)

low_priority_bus = EventBus('low-priority-bus', priority=1)
high_priority_bus = EventBus('high-priority-bus', priority=5)
EventBus.register_buses([low_priority_bus, high_priority_bus])

low_priority_queue = QueueConfig('low-priority-queue', low_priority_bus)
high_priority_queue = QueueConfig('high-priority-queue', high_priority_bus)
my_listener = MyListener([low_priority_queue, high_priority_queue])
my_listener.listen()
```